# Grails HttpBuilder URL encoded GET

Tags: xml, rest, grails, httpbuilder

I want to communicate with a webservice, which has a URL-based API. For example I have the following URL:

http://api.bla.com/aaa/bbb.ashx?Action=GetSecurityToken&vendorId=3

I can put the URL into the browser and get a XML page, with all details.

I want to get the XML page from my grails application, therefore i use the following code:

```
http = new HTTPBuilder('http://api.bla.com/aaa/bbb.ashx')
html = http.get( path : '/', query : [Action :"GetSecurityToken", vendorId: "3"] ) )
println html
```

Why doesnt this work. I get a bad request. How can I get the xml page from the URL above in my grails controller?

Answer (score 1):

I think that the final url will be http://api.bla.com/aaa/bbb.ashx/?Action=GetSecurityToken&vendorId=3 , because you defined your base url as http://api.bla.com/aaa/bbb.ashx and set the path of your call to `/`.

Try changing your base url like (taken from [this](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/doc/get.html) example):

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder('http://api.bla.com/aaa')
http.get( path : '/bbb.ashx',
          contentType : XML,
          query : [Action :"GetSecurityToken", vendorId: "3"] ) { resp, reader ->

  println "response status: ${resp.statusLine}"
  println 'Headers: -----------'
  resp.headers.each { h ->
    println " ${h.name} : ${h.value}"
  }
  println 'Response data: -----'
  System.out << reader
  println '\n--------------------'
}
```

Comment: I turned on logging for HTTPBuilder and discovered that setting path: '/' will actually get you the uri to the domain name + the query string: `http://api.bla.com/?Action=GetSecurityToken&vendorId=3`. Sergio's solution should work, but you could also just eliminate the path parameter altogether in your get call, so `http.get( query : [Action :"GetSecurityToken", vendorId: "3"] )`